# problems with css regarding menu items

Tags: css, menu, jsfiddle

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/frcdd/

This is a drop down menu using jquery. Now if you click on the fiddle you will see the problem.

When one clicks on a menu item say "canada", the menu will open fine and display the animation, however the background of the menu items will be clipped top and bottom. I am not sure what is going on. I suspect a CSS error somewhere but I have spent hours looking so here I am. Also, I can't seem to figure out how to change the text-decoration to none and change the hover, active, link, visited colors of the menu items.

```
div.container {
    background:#292B29;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your uls has a margin 16px. Put margin 0px on it

```
.container ul{
    margin: 0px; 
}
```

[Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frcdd/4/)

To change anything on visited anchors put pseudo class :visited

```
a:visited{
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: but if i use a:visited, won't the page I put the css on absorb these values as well? Is there no way to associate it with the specific div class?

Comment: sure...just specify an anchor that insight specific div like so - #specific_div_id a:visited and it fill afect only a's that insight your element http://jsfiddle.net/frcdd/8/